# How to run gatling with scala file name without simulation name?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I run the gatling with `./gatling.sh -s className` command.
But class name can be different from simulation file name.
For Example The simulation name below is **Test**,but scala file name can be different.The file name is **TestSimulation.scala.**
How can I run the simulation with file name?

```
 import io.gatling.core.Predef._
 import io.gatling.http.Predef._
 import scala.concurrent.duration._

 class Test extends Simulation {
   val httpConf = http.baseURL("url")
   var scn = scenario("Test")
        .exec(
            http("My Other Request")
              .get("/1")
   )

   setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(2000) over  (200 seconds)).protocols(httpConf))
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/files.html)

> In short, the Java file naming and positioning conventions should be preferred, despite the fact that Scala allows for greater flexibility in this regard.

So your class should be named `TestSimulation`, not `Test`

If you want to run your simulation as it is you can provide just `test` as the simulation name like:

```
gatling -s test
```

and it should start executing your simulation given it is under `user-files/simulations` or Gatling can find it somehow else.

Check out [How to Run a Simple Load Test with Gatling](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-run-a-simple-load-test-with-gatling) for more information if needed.

Comment: I will run my simulation such as gatling -sf /unique-simulation-folder/ without using -s argument becasuse only one simulation will be in folder.